# node.js / jQuery cross domain: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js.

I'm creating a simple node/express application that serves a single web page containing one button that when clicked makes a jQuery ajax request to an Express route.

The route callback makes an http.get request to openexchangerates.org for some json data containing foreign exchange rates. The JSON is then output to the Developer Tools console window.

The application works on the first button click, but on any subsequent clicks the console window displays:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/getFx net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

A screen grab of the Developer Tools console window shows the result of the first click, and then the second click when the connection is refused.

[image]

The error detail is as follows:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/getFx net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED    jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send    jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4   
n.extend.ajax           (index):18
(anonymous function)    jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
n.event.dispatch        jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
n.event.add.r.handle
```

My simple Node/Express application is as follows:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var data = "";
var json;

console.log( "__dirname", __dirname );
app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/') );

var options = {
  host:"openexchangerates.org",
  path:"/api/latest.json?app_id=<get free ID from openexchangerates.org>"
};

app.get("/", function( req, res ) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.get("/getfx", function(req, res) {
  console.log("Route: getFx");
  getFx(res);
})

function getFx(res) {
  console.log("http getFx");
  http.get(options, function (response) {
    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      //console.log("data:\n"+chunk);
      data += chunk;
    });
    response.on("end", function () {
      json = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log("http response end:");
      res.end( data );
    });
    response.on("error", function (e) {
      console.log("error:\n" + e.message);
    });
  })
}

app.listen(3000);
```

My html index page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Get FX</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log( "document ready");
           $("#btnFx").click(function() {
                console.log('clicked', this );
                $.ajax({
                    url : "http://127.0.0.1:3000/getFx",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(json) {
                        console.log("json returned:\n", json);
                    }
                });
            } );
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnFx" style="width:200px">Get foreign exchange rates</button>
</body>
```

For openexchangerates.org to serve the data, a free app id is required. Anyone able to help resolve this may have to go through their very short sign up:

That link is here:

https://openexchangerates.org/signup/free

However it's possible that my mistake is glowingly obvious to those with better Node/Express/jQuery knowledge.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What your console is saying (or any logs from node)?

Comment: @maque thanks for your response. The error detail is now below the image.

Comment: Your title is a bit missleading. this error has very little to do with cross-domain requests. or express. or jquery.

Comment: Apologies if it is misleading. It's the error that's listed in the console window. As my Node skills are in their infancy, I'm eager to understand what I'm doing wrong. I'll amend the title as soon as I best understand how to word it...

Comment: A problem begins here: `var data = "";` and ends when you don't re-empty it after using it. `JSON.parse(data);` should end up throwing an error on the second request. `data` should instead be defined inside the request callback before you bind to the data and end events. the same goes for your `json` var.

Comment: @KevinB, wow, thank you so much. I've just tested that and it works. The error is so far from the answer it will take me a few moments to think how best to reword the title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you defined your `data` and `json` vars is causing subsequent requests to fail. Since you defined them up front, all requests will re-use them, meaning by the time you JSON.parse `data` for the second request, `data` will contain two valid json strings, thus making one invalid json string. To fix this, define `data` and `json` farther down in the callback.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
//var data = "";
//var json;

console.log( "__dirname", __dirname );
app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/') );

var options = {
  host:"openexchangerates.org",
  path:"/api/latest.json?app_id=<get free ID from openexchangerates.org>"
};

app.get("/", function( req, res ) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.get("/getfx", function(req, res) {
  console.log("Route: getFx");
  getFx(res);
})

function getFx(res) {
  console.log("http getFx");
  http.get(options, function (response) {
    var data = "";
    var json;
    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      //console.log("data:\n"+chunk);
      data += chunk;
    });
    response.on("end", function () {
      console.log("http response end:");
      json = JSON.parse(data);
      res.json(json);
    });
    response.on("error", function (e) {
      console.log("error:\n" + e.message);
    });
  })
}

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping the JSON.parse in a try catch since it's coming from a 3rd party api, you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Issue comes from Cross origin requests protection which happens on localhost with chrome. Try to use other browser or just Allow origin to all hosts (*) or your host (http://localhost:3000):

```
app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/') );
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```